# Confused as to why CSS isn't working

Tags: css

I can't get my head round why this code isn't working.

http://www.goldrushme.com/views/answergarden.html

JQuery dynamically appends the container to add 2 'boxes', with classes '.two_q1' and '.two_q2'.

When you look at the CSS, the first box just doesn't seem to work, and chrome developer tools doesn't associate it with the correct CSS class, but I can't figure out why!

Any suggestions?

Cheers,

Rick

Comment: Please show us your jquery/JS function.

Comment: What do you mean with *this code isn't working*? What behaviour do you expect, and what result are you getting instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At line 325 of `default.css`, using Western encoding, I see this:

```
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}â€‹

.two_q1 {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
```

It seems like you have a non-printable character stuck before the selector. Remove it and the selector should work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a spacial char in between line.  remove it. It will work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would move your JavaScript to an external file, then in the scripts tab of the chrome inspector you can set breakpoints etc. which should help you work out what is not working